# npm shrinkwrap vs install passing the --save-exact flag

Tags: npm, npm-shrinkwrap

What's the different between using `npm shrinkwrap` or always installing dependencies passing the `-E` or `--save-exact|-E` flag?

ie.: `$ npm i redux -SE` **-SE** *being the shorthand to `--save --save-exact`*

I guess `shrinkwrap` will also take care of locking 'dependencies of our first level dependencies' but would it be a bad practice to always use `--save-exact` instead? If not, when or why would we ever need use the `--save-exact` flag?

Edit: I'm also starting to see people suggesting to config npm to install exact versions of dependencies by default:

ie.: `$ npm config set save-exact=true`

Now, if we do that, do we still need to `shrinkwrap` our project?

Answer (score 1):

save-exact work like just save this version for you but it wont lock dependecies of dependencies

shrinkwrap makes deep locking.